# Touchpad right button not working for right click on juno

Tags: release-juno

I have a dell xps with a touchpad with physical buttons.

After installing Juno my right button does not work for right click.

As far as I undestand from this article https://itsfoss.com/fix-right-click-touchpad-ubuntu/ this is a new behaviour from underlying drivers.

In this article there is a solution on how to reactivate the right click on gnome.

Is there a similar solution to reactivate this button with elementary ?

Regards
Seb

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same Problem with my XPS 13. The Solution was very easy.

System Settings > Mouse & Touchpad > Physical clicking (in the Touchpad area)

Set it from *Multitouch* to *Touchpad areas*.

This was changed in `Odin` (0.6) to:

System Settings > Mouse & Touchpad > Touchpad > Physical secondary clicking

Set it from *Multitouch* to *Areas*.

Comment: Google got bogged down with all sorts of non-elementary solutions to the problem making it hard for me to find this super easy solution to my dell inspirion trackpad right click not working. I looked at:
* https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/sln308258/precision-xps-ubuntu-general-touchpad-mouse-issue-fix?lang=en
* https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/5r1dky/touchpad_does_not_right_click_any_solutions/
as well as other semi-related pages. I only found this page because I started to ask how to fix my touchpad right click not working on elementaryos.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Worked in HP Omen Laptop

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I selected Hardware default in order to have it working.

Answer (score 0):

None of the settings fixed by Sony Vaio touchpad. Editing the gnome settings directly did fix my issue.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad click-method areas
```